# Jquery File Tree - how to display the root folder icon?

Tags: jquery, file, tree

Well I have my JQuery file tree working.

However I want to know how to display an icon and name for the root folder, as well as its contents listed in the tree.

Eg

```
.fileTree({ root: '/home/',
```

Displays a treeview of /home. But only the contents of it.

I want it to display the root folder 'home' at the top of the tree as well as its contents.

Any ideas what I'll need to modify in jQueryFileTree.js to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is you can display the top level icon and root folder BUT it would also display all the sub folders under it (Ex. fileTree({ root: '/',) would also display /var /tmp /user ..etc.).

What you can do is just put a static image & text above the  that displays the jTree.

```
<img src="folder_icon.png> /home  <br/>
<div id="file-tree" class="demo">
   Loading... <img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'spinner.gif')}"/>
</div>
```